# When I boot up I get an error message saying there is something wrong with my hard disk

Tags: boot, hard-drive

When I boot up I get an error message saying there is something wrong with my hard disk and to continue I must press f1. How do I find out if there really is something wrong with the disk or if this is a software error? After pressing f1 the computer has been working ok. This has been going on for some time and I do not believe there is anything wrong with the hard drive. Ubuntu 14.04.  If there it is a software problem how do I fix it?

Comment: Generally this suggests something is wrong with your hard disk, despite you successfully using it. Could you post the actual error message - that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), a set of applications designed to test hard drives and read their S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology) statistics:

Install Smartmontools : `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`

See what block devices are attached to the system : `ls /sys/block`

Check if your drive supports SMART : `sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda`

Enable SMART if it is disabled : `sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda`

Run a long test on your drive : `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda`

Review the results of the test once complete : `sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda`

If you see any amount of `Offline_Uncorrectable` errors then you want to consider replacing the drive immediately if you care about retaining the data.